Prove that $c \sup A = \sup(cA)$ for $c>0$.
I'm new to real analysis and trying to prove $\sup⁡(cA)=c\sup⁡(A)$ for $c>0$. Using this definition of least upper bound:
$s=\sup A$, where $s\in \mathbb R$ and $A\subseteq \mathbb R$ if

$\forall a\in A$, $a \leq s$,
$\forall \varepsilon >0$, $\exists b \in A$ such that $s-\varepsilon<b$.

Here's my proof:

Assume $s=\sup A$ where $c>0$, and define $cA=\{c a | a\in A  \} $,
$\forall a \in A$, $a \leq s \Rightarrow ca \leq c s$, where $ca\in cA$ (so $cs$ is an upper bound of $cA$),
$\forall \varepsilon>0 $, $\exists b \in A$ such that $s-\frac \varepsilon c <b \Rightarrow cs-\varepsilon <cb$, where $cb\in cA$.

Since $cs$ satisfies both properties, we can conclude $c\sup(A)=cs= \sup(cA)$.
Question: Is this proof correct? or is it rigorous enough? Thank you!

Looks good to me.

Another approach that just uses ordering: In the following $ a \in A$ is implicit. Since $a \le \sup A$ we have $ca \le c \sup A$ and so $\sup cA \le c \sup A$. Since $\sup cA \ge ca$, we have ${1 \over c} \sup cA \ge a$ and so ${1 \over c} \sup cA \ge \sup A$ from which we get $\sup cA \ge c \sup A$.

The proof looks correct and rigorous.
Note however that a proof being rigorous does not mean that it must be written using formal symbols like $\forall$.
And some wordings are strange, for example "Assume $s=\sup A$ where $c>0$". This is confusing since $c$ is not found in "$s=\sup A.$" Instead you probably want to say "Let $s=\sup A$ and assume $c>0.$"
Also, skip the parentheses around "so $cs$ is an upper bound of $cA$". This is a central conclusion, not just a parenthesis.
Usually, to show "$\forall \epsilon>0\ \exists \ldots$" one writes "Let $\epsilon>0$." and then shows the existence by giving an explicit example. So you could write something like
"Let $\epsilon>0.$ Then, since $s=\sup A,$ there exists $b\in A$ such that $s-\epsilon/c < b.$ But then $cs - \epsilon < bs,$ i.e. there exists $b' \in cA$ (take $b'=cb$) such that $cs - \epsilon < b'.$"

Thank you for your detailed comments!
